# VBA - printing empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that takes information from **under** two specific column headers in opening files and prints them to a masterfile.

One column is empty every few files and I need it to print empty cells to column 2 of my masterfile in the range of the filled cells of column 3. The loop finds the last used row when printing to the sheet, so even if they are empty, it will print over them. I'm assuming that is what I would need to fix. Also, if there are a few occupied cells followed by many empty cells, it needs to print both of those to the masterfile.

**Explanation of code:**

*My code prints out information to my masterfile into column 3, then column 2, then column 1 based on the number of cells is in column 3. There can be blank cells in column 2 but there should not be any blank cells that occur in column 3; **columns 2 and 3 should always be the same length** (spaces included)*

The phrase "empty HOLDER" prints to column 2 if there are no values at all in a holder (but it only prints that once and I need it to print it for as many cells equivalent to column 3 are empty. I will change that phrase to just " ", but the words are just to help me see what the program is doing.

The phrase "NO HOLDERS PRESENT!" prints out when there is no header file HOLDER found anywhere in the sheet.

Any ideas how I can go about fixing this please?

It currently looks like (1) and I need it to look like (2)

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

```
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = " empty TOOL "
                    End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = " empty HOLDER "
                    End If
                Else
                    'if no HOLDER is found on the sheet
                    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO HOLDERS PRESENT!"
                End If
```

**FULL CODE IF NEEDED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range
    Dim hc12 As Range, n As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2

    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet

            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet'
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the CUTTING TOOL header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = " empty TOOL "
                    End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO CUTTING TOOLS PRESENT"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc3 = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="HOLDER", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        'if no items are under the HOLDER header
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = " empty HOLDER "
                    End If
                Else
                    'if no HOLDER is found on the sheet
                    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO HOLDERS PRESENT!"
                End If
'(5)
                'print the file name to Column 4
                StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                With ws
                'Print TDS name by searching for header
                    If Not ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                        Set TDS = ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                    Else
                        'print the file name wihtout the extension
                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = GetFilenameWithoutExtension(objFile.Name)
                    End If
                    i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                End With

                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
'(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub
'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim theValue As String
    Dim splitValues As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dataRange = ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    ' If there are no values in this column then return an empty dictionary
    ' If there are no values in this column, the dataRange will start at the row
    ' *above* ch and end at ch
    If (dataRange.Row = (ch.Row - 1)) And (dataRange.Rows.count = 2) And (Trim(ch.Value) = "") Then
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
        theValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(theValue) = 0 Then
            theValue = "none"
        End If
            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ";")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If
            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                splitValues = Split(theValue, ",")
                theValue = splitValues(0)
            End If

            If Not dict.exists(theValue) Then
            dict.Add theValue, theValue
        End If
    Next cell
Exit_Function:
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
        'If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function
'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
'(12)
'get the file name without the extension
Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(ByVal FileName)
  Dim Result, i
  Result = FileName
  i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If (i > 0) Then
    Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
  End If
  GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
```

Comment: You should include link of the spread sheet as is big code to work

Comment: will do. the masterfile or the files that it is opening? they're private material so it would have to just be a sample file. @user4908244 . Also, what is the best way to include a link of a file?

Comment: @Taylor - is this the same piece of code as your other questions? If so, why not compile all the existing answers, including the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93002/open-files-copy-area-under-header-print-to-mastersheet) before posting new questions?

Comment: The files that has the codes on and u can delete the private stuff

Comment: Can you add an If Statement before writing to master file?  If header then "Empty" Or if "" then Empty

Comment: @ChipsLetten by compile do you mean test those pieces of code out myself and compile them? If so, I have done that and played with it, altered a lot. Whenver I have a follow up question people say it's bad to ask another question within the question so I should just start a new one

Comment: @user4908244 I'll do that. Is there some what I can upload a file to this page or should I upload it somewhere else and add a link? I've never uploaded a file to stackoverflow before

Comment: @HolmesIV it is printing a range at a time. So if there is one value and 5 blanks it sees the range as not empty but will only grab the one value. I do not know how to change it to grab blanks as well

Comment: @Taylor, well it wouldn't be the prettiest, but I suppose at the end of the import you could run another sub to fix the issues, it seems like they are easy to recognize.

Comment: @HolmesIV right but I'm not worried about it being pretty, I'm saying if there are blanks after a filled cell it would not be considered blank or "empty", unless you're thinking of implementing this somewhere else that I'm not seeing. Could you explain more in detail and with code what you mean. I am new to VBA so the issues are not easy to recognize for me.

Comment: I meant compile in the English language meaning, not the technical one. You have several questions floating around with answers and the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93002/open-files-copy-area-under-header-print-to-mastersheet) but you have not  yet changed your code before you post another question. This makes it hard to understand your code and answer your next question.

Comment: I agree that you should ask a new question when you get a new problem. You should also pretty up your code before you post it - remove all the old code and a lot of the blank lines. Makes it too hard to read otherwise.

Comment: @Taylor I am saying after you finish filling you masterfile, run a subroutine that will loop through the columns replacing Blanks and Headers with "Empty".

Comment: @HolmesIV , ah I understand. The problem is, my following code prints to the next empty line so a lot of time the blank cells will just get printed over and thus I have no empty cells to replace

Comment: @ChipsLetten okay, thank you! I'll remember to do that next time!

Comment: Please edit your code in this post to remove all the old commented out code and a lot of the blank lines.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Sorry for the messy code and question. I have added more information about what my code does, what I need it to do as well as pictures to expain that, and cleaned up my code! I hope that helps. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @ChipsLetten I actually think I have now gotten it to work! Thank you for all of your help. I posted my solution below. Do you see anything wrong with it that would cause problems in the future?

Comment: It now works to print empty spaces where the HOLDER or CUTTING TOOL column is completely empty; but when there is one value followed by 5 blank spaces, it will only print the one value. Any ideas? @ChipsLetten 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897395/vba-print-empty-cells-following-occupied-cell

Comment: Or do you know how I would fix to add spaces after an occupied cell @HolmesIV
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897395/vba-print-empty-cells-following-occupied-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:** Had it print empty " " down the range equal to whatever is occupied in column 3.

**Section that fixed the code:**

```
(4)
...
        Else
            'if no items are under the HOLDER header
            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " "
```